# Eliminar diccionario vacio de una lista

Tags: python-3.x, lista

```
[{}, {'producto': 'arroz', 'cantidad': 2, 'valor': 3}, {}, {'producto': 'ki2i', 'cantidad': 2, 'valor': 4}]
```

quisiera eliminar los `{}` *vacios* de la lista sin afectar las otras posiciones, qué me recomiendan?

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: Estoy intentando eliminar los {} que hay en la lista sin afectar los que tienen contenido, pero no se como

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Richard:

Podrías verificar si elemento tiene contenido con un if:

```
lista = [{}, {'producto': 'arroz', 'cantidad': 2, 'valor': 3}, {}, {'producto': 'ki2i', 'cantidad': 2, 'valor': 4}]

lista_final = [elemento for elemento in lista if elemento]

print(lista_final)
```

De esta forma el resultado será el siguiente:

```
[{'producto': 'arroz', 'cantidad': 2, 'valor': 3}, {'producto': 'ki2i', 'cantidad': 2, 'valor': 4}]
```

También podrías usar otros métodos como funciones de filtrado, pero para lo que necesitas esta sería una opción correcta.